# datepicker not binding the value to the angular form control

Tags: jquery, angular, datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using [jquery-datetimepicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) within the angular projects. But when I select the date in the date picker the value is not bound to the form control.

I tried so far.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      startDate: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('value: ', this.myForm.value);
    console.log('the whole form and its controls: ', this.myForm);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    (window as any).$('.pickDateOneTimeStartDate').datetimepicker({
      allowInputToggle: true,
      timepicker: false,
      format: 'M d, Y',
      minDate: Date.now,
      scrollMonth: false,
      scrollInput: false,
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <hello [myForm]="myForm"></hello>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="pickDateOneTimeStartDate">
         <input formControlName="startDate" aria-label="Start Date"  [ngClass]="{
          'is-invalid':
          myForm.controls['startDate'].errors
      }" class="form-control">

      <div *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'startDate')" class="invalid-feedback">
      This field is required
      </div>
     </div>

  </div>      
     `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() myForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zt4thj) implementation

when I add onChangeDateTime on the date picker the value in the form objects gets updated but is still not shown in the input box.

updated:

```
var self = this;
(window as any).$('.pickDateOneTimeStartDate').datetimepicker({
  allowInputToggle: true,
  timepicker: false,
  format: 'M d, Y',
  minDate: Date.now,
  scrollMonth: false,
  scrollInput: false,
  onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
    self.myForm.value.startDate = $input.val();
  },
});
```

output:

```
{
  "startDate": "Jun 30, 2022"
}
```

Comment: Save yourself from a boatload of pain and don’t combine jQuery with Angular. Really not a good idea.

Comment: I have been maintaining the old project that uses the jQuery with angular 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the function with

```
onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
   self.myForm.controls.startDate.setValue($input.val());
},
```